# Does a console app use login credentials for Azure Key Vault Secrets

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-keyvault, azure-authentication

I was converting a test console app to use Azure Key Vault by copying a code from another application and I was surprised to see the console app was able to get the secret without any configuration in the Azure Portal. I had assumed I would need to link the console app to the secrets so the code had permission to pull the secrets. Is the console app using my login credentials to authenticate? This isn't about the code but here's a quick sample.

```
        string _dbString = "";
        _dbString = GetSecrets(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DatabaseSecretUrl"]).Result.Value;

        private static async Task<SecretBundle> GetSecrets(string Url)
        {
            AzureServiceTokenProvider azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
            KeyVaultClient keyVaultClient = new KeyVaultClient(new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(azureServiceTokenProvider.KeyVaultTokenCallback));
            return await keyVaultClient.GetSecretAsync(Url).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
AzureServiceTokenProvider azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
```

this line does indeed do attempt to use an existing logon session to your Azure account. If you did for instance an `az login` before, it will be able to use that. Also, if your computer is AzureAD joined, it might be able to use those credentials as well.

Comment: When I first ran the console I had already logged into the portal and I had also run a PowerShell script that prompted me for credentials. I shut down PowerShell and the console app still work so I assume my login to the portal is where it's getting my authentication. Since this is a test app this is fine, I was just confused as to how it was working.

Comment: I found a code sample for ```AzureServiceTokeProvider``` and sure enough the 3rd listed method to get a token says ```Active Directory Integrated Authentication (for local development). To use integrated Windows authentication, your domain’s Active Directory must be federated with Azure Active Directory. Your application must be running on a domain-joined machine under a user’s domain credentials.```

Comment: It can also use an account in Visual Studio on Windows.